# Сделать так что бы картинка двигалась по кратчайшей линии. С помощью функции прямой y=k*x+b. k=(y1-y2)/(x1-x2) ; b=y1-((y1-y2)*x1). JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```js
      var person = document.getElementById('person');
      function start() {
        var string_start_x = person.style.left;
        var string_start_y = person.style.top;
        var start_x = Number(string_start_x.slice(0, string_start_x.length - 2));
        var start_y = Number(string_start_y.slice(0, string_start_y.length - 2));
        var end_x = Number(document.data.x.value);
        var end_y = Number(document.data.y.value);
        var inc_x = (start_x < end_x)? 1: -1;
        var inc_y = (start_y < end_y)? 1: -1;
        move(start_x, end_x, inc_x, start_y, end_y, inc_y);
      }
  
      function move(x, end_x, inc_x, y, end_y, inc_y) {
        if ((x == end_x) && (y == end_y)) return;
        if (x != end_x) x += inc_x;
        if (y != end_y) y += inc_y;
        person.style.left = x + "px";
        person.style.top = y + "px";
        setTimeout(move, 10, x, end_x, inc_x, y, end_y, inc_y);
      }
```

```html
      <form name="data">
        X:
        <input type="text" name="x">
        <br>
        Y:
        <input type="text" name="y">
          <br>
          <input type="button" value="Start" onClick="start()">
      </form>
      <img id="person" style="position: absolute; top:100px; left:500px; border:1px solid red;"    width=200; height=200; src="images/person.jpg">
```

Каким образом изменить код так, что бы изображение двигалось по кратчайшей прямой, а не сначала по х а потом по у

Comment: в чем заключается вопрос?

Comment: ну каким образом изменить код  так что бы изображение двигалось по кратчайшей прямой, а не сначала по х а потом по у

Comment: не использовать `inc_x` и `inc_y` а на каждом шаге рассчитывать координаты картинки по формуле

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У тебя есть две точки:

1. (X<sub>1</sub>,Y<sub>1</sub>) - координаты левого верхнего угла картинки
2. (X<sub>2</sub>,Y<sub>2</sub>) - координаты точки, куда картинка должна переместиться

Далее по указанным тобой в вопросе формулам можно вывести функцию, которая по заданной координате `x` вернет координату `y`, Например так:

```
function createFunc(x1,y1,x2,y2){
    var k=(y1-y2)/(x1-x2); 
    var b=y1-(k*x1);
    return function (x){
        return k*x+b;
    }
}
```

Далее по таймауту меняя координаты x от текущей до заданной - получаем соответствующую координату y и перемещаем картинку в полученную точку.

---

**Важно:** данный способ не подходит, если картинку нужно двигать *вертикально*, так как в этом случае `x1==x2` и при расчете `k` будет получен `Infinity`

---

```js
function createFunc(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
  var k = (y1 - y2) / (x1 - x2);
  var b = y1 - (k * x1);
  return function(x) {
    return k * x + b;
  }
}
var person = document.getElementById('person');

function start() {
  var rect = person.getBoundingClientRect();
  var x1 = rect.left;
  var y1 = rect.top;
  var x2 = Number(document.data.x.value);
  var y2 = Number(document.data.y.value);
  var stepCount = 100;
  var step = (x2 - x1) / stepCount;
  move(x1, step, x2, createFunc(x1, y1, x2, y2));
}

function move(x, step, endX, func) {
  if (Math.floor(x) == endX) return;
  if (x != endX) x += step;
  var y = func(x);
  person.style.left = Math.floor(x) + "px";
  person.style.top = Math.floor(y) + "px";
  setTimeout(move, 10, x, step, endX, func);
}
```

```html
<form name="data">
  X:
  <input type="text" name="x">
  <br> Y:
  <input type="text" name="y">
  <br>
  <input type="button" value="Start" onclick="start()">
</form>
<img id="person" style="position: absolute; top:100px; left:500px; border:1px solid red;" width=200; height=200; src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=200%C3%97200&w=200&h=200">
```

Comment: А чего не css-то?

Comment: И чего не сделать нормально, чтобы можно было двигать и вертикально?

Comment: @Qwertiy, решил не менять передвижение как у автора. Ну вообще говоря по уравнению прямой, которое у заголовке, нельзя построить вертикальную прямую :-) так что, вертикальное перемещение нужно рассматривать отдельно :)

Comment: Ещё надо бы setTimeout в requestAnimationFrame превратить. И десятка там какая-то сомнительная.

Comment: @Qwertiy, а это у тебя был вопрос на мете про два ряда кнопок в сниппете? у меня сейчас - та же ерунда. Причем и в моем ответе и в вопросе

Comment: [Держи](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4949/178988). Всё равно его никто не фиксит :(

Comment: @Qwertiy, ээээх, но возможно он появляется, когда открыт сниппет, и добавляются новые ответы, при загрузке этих ответов кнопки дублируются

Comment: Перепиши этот коммент на мету) Или дополни вопрос, если уверен.

Comment: @Qwertiy, уже не уверен :-)

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы картинка ехала под углом, вам нужно задать коэффицент либо для inc_x либо для inc_y, примерно так можно -

```
var dx = end_x - start_x;
var dy = end_y - start_y;
if(dx > dy) inc_y *= dy/dx;
else  inc_x *= dx/dy;
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
~function() {
  var img = document.querySelector('img');
  var left = 500, top = 100;
  var form = document.forms.data;
  var SPEED = 128; /* px per second */

  document.getElementById('go').addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    var x = +form.x.value, y = +form.y.value;
    var dist = Math.sqrt((left-x)*(left-x) + (top-y)*(top-y));
    
    img.style.transform = 'translate('+x+'px,'+y+'px)';
    img.style.transitionDuration = dist / SPEED + 's';
    
    left = x, top = y;
  })
}()
```

```css
form {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

label {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: .5em;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
  transform: translate(500px, 100px);
  transition: transform 1s linear;
}
```

```html
<form name="data">
  <label>X: <input type="text" name="x"></label>
  <label>Y: <input type="text" name="y"></label>
  <input id="go" type="button" value="Start"> <!-- TODO: use submit -->
</form>
<img width=200 height=200 src="//www.gravatar.com/avatar/cbfaff96665b7567defe1b34a883db8b?s=200&d=identicon&r=PG">
```

Comment: ты б хоть описание добавил что у тебя тут твориться :-)

Comment: А что тут такого творится?)

Comment: Где расчеты :-) где функция прямой? что за трансформ? и т.д. :-)